# Composition of enumerations

Tags: c

Is there a way to make a composition of multiple enum in C ?
I would like to have a common enum that will be used in other enumerations.

For example, I would like to write the following code:

```
enum common_e {
   COMMON_LITERAL_0,
   COMMON_LITERAL_1
}

enum first_e {
   common_e, // <- Somehow I would like to have the two common_e's literals here
   FIRST_LITERAL_0,
}

enum another_e {
   common_e, // <- Somehow I would like to have the two common_e's literals here
   ANOTHER_LITERAL_0,
   ANOTHER_LITERAL_1
}
```

My concern is to keep the common literals in the same order in the sub-enumarations as they are used as ID for function pointer arrays.

Is there a solution to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
enum common_e {
   COMMON_LITERAL_0,
   COMMON_LITERAL_1,
   COMMON_MAX
}

enum first_e {
   FIRST_LITERAL_0 = COMMON_MAX,
}

enum another_e {
   ANOTHER_LITERAL_0 = COMMON_MAX,
   ANOTHER_LITERAL_1
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`enum`s are not namespaced, so you cannot have two enumerators with the same name.  So no, you cannot do this, even with the preprocessor or other magic.

If you simply want the enum values to carry on where the common one left off, then how about:

```
enum common_e {
    COMMON_LITERAL_0,
    COMMON_LITERAL_1,
    COMMON_LITERAL_END__
};

enum first_e {
    FIRST_LITERAL_0 = COMMON_LITERAL_END__,
    FIRST_LITERAL_1
};
```

Comment: Oh yeah! You have got it I think that's what I need. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Well, you *could* conceivably do something like this:

```
#define COMMON_E(N) N##_COMMON_LITERAL_0, \
                    N##_COMMON_LITERAL_1

enum first_e {
   COMMON_E(FIRST), // <- Somehow I would like to have the two common_e's literals here
   FIRST_LITERAL_0,
};

enum another_e {
   COMMON_E(ANOTHER), // <- Somehow I would like to have the two common_e's literals here
   ANOTHER_LITERAL_0,
   ANOTHER_LITERAL_1
};
```

Although I'm not sure what the benefit of this would be...

Problem is that enums aren't namespaced, so you have to supply distinct names (hence the macro parameter).

Comment: That's an interesting solution.I will consider it in my application, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in C. You'll simply have to define multiple enums.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do precisely what you ask, but you can do some things that are almost as good. Each of these solutions relies upon the ability to set the values of specific enum members.

You could put all of your names in a single enum:

```
enum every_e {
   // common values
   COMMON_LITERAL_0,
   COMMON_LITERAL_1,
   MAX_COMMON_LITERAL = COMMON_LITERAL_1,

   // First set of extra values
   FIRST_LITERAL_0 = MAX_COMMON_LITERAL+1,
   FIRST_LITERAL_1,
   FIRST_LITERAL_2,

   // Second set of extra values
   ANOTHER_LITERAL_0 = MAX_COMMON_LITERAL+1,
   ANOTHER_LITERAL_1
};
```

If you do want to use distinct enum types, you could use the same trick:

```
enum common_e {
   COMMON_LITERAL_0,
   COMMON_LITERAL_1,
   MAX_COMMON_LITERAL = COMMON_LITERAL_1
};

enum first_e {
   FIRST_LITERAL_0 = MAX_COMMON_LITERAL+1,
};

enum another_e {
   ANOTHER_LITERAL_0 = MAX_COMMON_LITERAL+1,
   ANOTHER_LITERAL_1
};
```

Comment: Don't give `MAX_COMMON_LITERAL` an explicit value, to prevent the maintenance headache of updating it every time you add a new `common_e` enumerator...

Comment: Thanks, @Oli. You are right. But since you and @c-smile have already posted, I won't bother to change this one.